# I was using colab: I want to run a .py file having argparse function to train a model

Tags: python, kernel, google-colaboratory, transformer-model, pre-trained-model

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    
    """Parameters"""
    parser  = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = "Emotion Classifier" )
    parser.add_argument( "--batch", type=int, help = "batch_size", default = 1)
    
    parser.add_argument( "--epoch", type=int, help = 'training epohcs', default = 10) # 12 for iemocap
    parser.add_argument( "--norm", type=int, help = "max_grad_norm", default = 10)
    parser.add_argument( "--lr", type=float, help = "learning rate", default = 1e-6) # 1e-5
    parser.add_argument( "--sample", type=float, help = "sampling trainign dataset", default = 1.0) # 

    parser.add_argument( "--dataset", help = 'MELD or EMORY or iemocap or dailydialog', default = 'MELD')
    
    parser.add_argument( "--pretrained", help = 'roberta-large or bert-large-uncased or gpt2 or gpt2-large or gpt2-medium', default = 'roberta-large')    
    parser.add_argument( "--initial", help = 'pretrained or scratch', default = 'pretrained')
    parser.add_argument('-dya', '--dyadic', action='store_true', help='dyadic conversation')
    parser.add_argument('-fr', '--freeze', action='store_true', help='freezing PM')
    parser.add_argument( "--cls", help = 'emotion or sentiment', default = 'emotion')
        
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    streamHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
    
    # Add the line below to fix the issue.
    sys.exit(main())
```

here's the error colab is showing

```
usage: colab_kernel_launcher.py [-h] [--batch BATCH] [--epoch EPOCH] [--norm NORM] [--lr LR]
                                [--sample SAMPLE] [--dataset DATASET] [--pretrained PRETRAINED]
                                [--initial INITIAL] [-dya] [-fr] [--cls CLS]
colab_kernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-1fba85a1-85fd-4471-a790-9c103c9dcac9.json
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3561: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

I have a `train.py` file, that I want to run on my `colab`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: as I remember you can send arguments directly to code like `args = parser.parse_args( ["--sample", "your_filename"] )`. Eventually you can add parameters directly to `sys.argv` like `sys.argv.append("--sample")` `sys.argv.append("your_filename")` before you create `parser`

Comment: BTW: you could use `print( sys.argv )` to see what values are send to code - probably `colab` has some values in `sys.argv` which makes problem. You should rather put own values directly in `parse_args(...)`

Answer (score 0):

When you run `parse_args()` then this gets values from `sys.argv`.
I can't test it but when server runs `colab` then it may puts in `sys.argv` some information for `colab` and this makes problem.

But you can put your values directly in `parse_args()` like

```
args = parser.parse_args( ["--sample", "your_filename"] )
```

or with empty list to use default values

```
args = parser.parse_args( [] )
```

---

**BTW:**

I don't see if your code uses `args` in any place - so I don't know if you really needs `ArgumentParser` and rest. Maybe you should remove it.

If you really use `args` in `main()` then it would be more readable to send it as argument like

```
def main(args):       # get `args` in function 
    # ... code ...

# ... 

sys.exit(main(args))  # send `args` to function
```